# Sencha Touch Build production app not working as expected

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am using Ext.plugin.PullRefresh plugin which is working fine when I directly run my app on 
the browser but when I build my production through sencha cmd 4.0 its duplicating my content whenever I pull to refesh.

I have already used idProperty on my model.

My Jsonp:

```
callback({"Message":"Success","Post":[{"id":"35","UserId":"faisalkhalid690","Content":"lol","Time":"2013-12-03 05:28:15"},{"id":"50","UserId":"faisalkhalid","Content":"asdfasdfasdf","Time":"2013-12-03 05:52:27"},{"id":"51","UserId":"faisalkhalid","Content":"sadfasdfasdf","Time":"2013-12-03 05:52:38"},{"id":"52","UserId":"faisalkhalid","Content":"holloa","Time":"2013-12-03 05:52:50"},{"id":"70","UserId":"faisalkhalid690","Content":"hello","Time":"2013-12-04 23:22:52"}]});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('talkbag.model.Comments', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
           idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'UserId', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'Content', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'Time', type: 'auto' }

        ]
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('talkbag.store.Comments', {
extend:'Ext.data.Store',

storeId:'Comments',
config:{
    autoLoad: true,
       model:'talkbag.model.Comments',
         proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url : 'http://www.litemake.com/ViewComments.php?Pid='+talkbag.User.PostId,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'Post'
            }
        }
    }

});
```

View:

```
Ext.define('talkbag.view.ViewPost.ViewCommentDetail', {
extend:'Ext.Panel',


xtype:'ViewCommentDetail',


requires:['Ext.plugin.PullRefresh'],

extend:'Ext.Panel',
config:{
layout:'vbox',
  items:
 [{
  xtype:'appbar',

 },{  
  flex:1,

xtype:'list',
  store:'Comments', 
  plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                pullRefreshText: 'Pull down for new Comments',

            }
        ],

    disableSelection :true,

itemTpl:'<table><tr><td width="80px"><table align="center"><tr><td align="center"><img src="http://www.litemake.com/getPic.php?userId={UserId}" heigth="30px" width="30px"/></td></tr><tr><td style="font-size:0.6em">{UserId}</td></tr></table></td><td style="padding-left:20px"><table><tr><td style="font-size:0.7em; padding:0px 0px 5px 0px">{Content}</td></tr><tr><td style="font-size:0.5em">{Time}</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>',

}]
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a requires for it? that is

requires:['Ext.plugin.PullRefresh']

or something like that?

Comment: also, I've had similar issues with duplicating content based on timing. I like to explicitly to my own store.load() and not use the autoload option making sure that I only call it once

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of duplicating record issue, In my case i have put an autogenerated id field in my json, like this way

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "ContactName": "Aanitha Ps",

        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ContactName": "Aby",
        }
        ]
}
```

and reference that id field in my model, i think sencha some times not taking model default id field.

Comment: I am also doing the same , it works but only when testing through localhost.When generate production build of my app than only I have duplication issues.